# Ajax request with a redirect, unable to get Cookies

Tags: ajax, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have an $.ajax request that hits and API. The API returns four cookies and then performs a (302) redirect.

```
    $.ajax({
  url: authUrl,
  type: 'post',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  dataType: 'text',
  data: dataObj,
})
.done(function (response) {
    console.log('response');
    console.log(response);
    let myCookies = document.cookie;
    console.log(myCookies);
  });
```

I'm trying to get the cookies inside the $.ajax, but the redirect causes the code in the .done to never execute. [image]

Even if I try to get the cookies in the console (where I can see the cookies and their values), I get nothing back.

This is happening inside a Chrome Extension, but even if I run this outside the extension I get the same result.

Comment: did you tried `success` callback instead of `done()`??

Comment: I have. But I’m using JQuery 3.x, and .success is deprecated in favor of .done.